# trouble plotting charts through vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to plot a graph with an interval difference of 0.3. So the x-axis will look like it starts from 0.00, 0.03, 0.06....

However, my graph obtained is very different from what i wanted.

```
Sub plottinggraph()

    Dim LastRowOfA As Long, LastRowOfB As Long, LastRowOfG As Long
    Dim ColumnARngData As Range, ColumnBRngData As Range
    Dim xAxes As Axis, yAxes As Axis

    Dim cht As Shape
    Set cht = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart
    With cht.Chart
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = "X VS Y"
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
        
        
        Set srsNew = .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "X, Y"
        .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        With srsNew
            .XValues = ColumnARngData
            .Values = ColumnBRngData
        End With
        
        Set xAxes = .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
        With xAxes
            .HasTitle = True
            .AxisTitle.Text = "X"
        End With
            
        Set yAxes = .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)
        With yAxes
            .HasTitle = True
            .AxisTitle.Text = "Y"
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I would suggest that you start record macro, create the graph as you want it, turn record off and examine the code that is created. Alternatively you could examine the created chart directly and see what axes, chart area etc settings are set to - modify them to what you want and then reflect the manual changes in your code

Comment: i did so, but it is redundant as i dont know how to change to to have a interval of 0.3 for the x-axis

Comment: if you manually create a chart as you want it to be then it is impossible to be redundant. You will have achived what you want to, namely VBA to fully automate what you want to do. Why dont you record changing the interval too?

Comment: i did, but it dosent change the way that i wanted it to be. I keyed in the value of 0.30 and nothing change

Comment: This wont look great formatting but if i record then i get this `ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnit = 5
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MinorUnit = 3
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).TickMarkSpacing = 100`

Comment: The x-axis become a thick line, it dosent garner what i wanted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```vb
Sub plottinggraph()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim xVals As Range, yVals As Range
    Dim co As Shape, cht As Chart
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set xVals = ws.Range("A4", ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    Set yVals = xVals.Offset(0, 1) 'colB

    Set co = ws.Shapes.AddChart
    Set cht = co.Chart
    
    With cht
        'always remove any possible "autoplotted" series...
        Do While .SeriesCollection.Count > 0
            .SeriesCollection(1).Delete
        Loop
        
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = "X VS Y"
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
        
        With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .XValues = xVals
            .Values = yVals
            .Name = "X, Y"
            .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        End With
        
        With .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary)
            .HasTitle = True
            .AxisTitle.Text = "X"
            .MinimumScale = 0
            .MaximumScale = Application.Max(xVals)
            .MajorUnit = 0.3
        End With
            
        With .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)
            .HasTitle = True
            .AxisTitle.Text = "Y"
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

It's sometimes a bit of a pain working with charts but Ok once you get the hang of it.  The macro recorder is your friend here - even if you just use it to figure out how to address a specific aspect/property of your chart.